# How asp .net handles concurrent user requests?

Tags: asp.net

This is for looking for an answer to a question i faced in  a technical discussion.

In a travel booking website there were 50 ticket's available.
Now only one more ticket left.2 users hitting the web server at the same time,
considering Asp .net can handle concurrent requests.

q.
1) How asp .net handles this requests?

2) There is a way for one of the user to get that last ticket.what is it?

I think understanding asp .net architecture deep is require to answer this question.

can anyone give me some insight.

Thanks
SNA

Comment: what i heard from he discussion itself is,many travel web sites because of some reason (may be missing something while implementing) people tweak (http get post) and get the ticket.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) How asp .net handles this requests?

Concurrently.

> 2) There is a way for one of the user to get that last ticket.what is it?

It will depend on what you mean by *getting a ticket*. If by getting a ticket you mean updating a field in the database then it's up to your database to handle this. If you use transactions it's probably the first SQL query that initiates the UPDATE that will succeed and the second will fail if you use some sort of constraints at the database level. But once again all that will depend on the specific implementation.

Comment: if both the user hit the servcer exactly the same time.Since asp .net handles request concurrently ,both the query to update status(probably booked=true something like that)will initaite.if it is query which user query get precedence? how asp .net decide this?

Comment: @SNA, ASP.NET doesn't decide that. It executes both requests in parallel. If in the code behind you use ADO.NET to connect to a database, all will depend on how your database will behave if 2 concurrent SQL requests are thrown at it. This really has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: Now one more question ..in the discussion it is mentioned ,using (HTTP Post or get) ther is a way to get that ticket.. even msmq is mentioned.Is it true .or how this happen's?again server implemetation is unknown to user who accees the page

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: well.In the same discussion one more question asked was.(Using HTTP post or get or msmq) people usually hack the site in real scenario's and get the ticket if there is only one ticket left.is it possible?

Comment: How do you expect me answer this question without me knowing the implementation of the system? You need to provide a lot more details and specific code samples before anyone can answer this. But if you are saying that there are users able to hack the site, then I guess the answer to your question is: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really worry about front-end concurrency in this case, IIS will take care of that for you. Much more important would be proper database implementation with carefully selected transaction isolation levels, deadlock handling etc.